# Angular $http.get not working on my device

Tags: angularjs, json, http, get

my js file is,

```
var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);

  countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('js/countries.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.countries = data;
  });
});
```

its fine when I emulate it on my android phone. but in my chrome browser running under windows 7 does not load the json. help me please......

Comment: check the console

Comment: Are you accessing the page via the `file:///` URL perhaps?

Comment: And please stop using success(). It's been deprecated for a long time now. Use `then(function(response) {$scope.countries = response.data; })`.

Comment: neither success nor then works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.then` to resolve your `request`. code snippet:

```
var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);

countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.countries - {};
  var promise = $http.get('js/countries.json');
   promise.then(function (data) {
     $scope.countries = data;
   }), function(reason) {
    //on error - use $log is better
   console.log('Failed: ' + reason);
  };
});
```

Comment: though i have tried and failed with .then() earlier, but this code looks like it will tell me the reason through the log. thanks a lot. got something new to try.